# Spring MVC: is using forms in the service layer a good practice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Let's say there is an application which uses the `forms` package and `<whatever>Form.java` for validation purposes in the controller layer, so every request which needs validation has a corresponding `<requestName>Form.java` class.

This results in controllers methods signatures looking like this:

**TemplateController.java**

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<SmsMessageTemplate> create(@Valid @RequestBody Mono<TemplateForm> templateForm)
```

and then there is a service layer with method signatures looking like this:

**TemplateService.java**

```
public Mono<SmsMessageTemplate> create(TemplateForm formData) {...}
```

It is also possible to implement it like so:

**TemplateService.java**

```
public Mono<SmsMessageTemplate> create(String template name, String templateText) {...}
```

Which way is better and why? I think passing the `Form` classes to the service layer may be mixing of the layers concept and one should keep forms in the controller layer for a better understanding of the parameters passed without a need to navigate through classes back and forth. Do I miss something?

Comment: This sounds a lot like an opinion-based question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such decisions trully depend on various factors f.e:
- the complexity and volume of the project (is it just a small service, or a full blown CMS / ERPS etc?)

- are you going to be re-using the service in other modules/projects
- are you going to distribute service interface jars ?
  (then you need to think about the modules and perhaps the *Form object will not even be at the controller side - you wouldn't want to distribute your controller classes to 3rd party clients)
- what about a form that contains 20 fields ? you surelly wont pass 20 arguments
- what about the case of a service method that does CRUD on complex entities, say a User ? you will probably have a couple of forms / validations (register, edit) and perhaps different types of users with different options so types * actions forms. (in which case you may consider a User domain object (in a domain package) and multiple controller side form objects (you will probably need to populate a User object from/to a Form).

generally speaking, as mentioned above, it's very opinion-based but in my opinion the overall complexity and envisaged size of each project will affect your final decision.